# How come I can't use message.user.tag?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to get the 4-digit tag of the person who used the command !hours, but discord won't recognize user.tag

```
import discord
from discord import message
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

##########HOURS##########

chung_victor = [21, 10]

##########HOURS##########

    # chung_victor
    if usertag == 5308:
        h = chung_victor[0]
        m = chung_victor[1]
        
        await ctx.send(f'> You currently have {h} hours and {m} minutes!')
```

And when I use !hours, I get the error message

```
Ignoring exception in command hours:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 36, in hours
    usertag = message.user.tag
AttributeError: module 'discord.message' has no attribute 'user'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
        await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
    File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
        await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
    File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
        raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
    discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: module 'discord.message' has no attribute 'user'
```

Comment: It’s discord.py, not discord.js…

Comment: Try `message.author.discriminator`

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you see to get user name you need to use it as `user.name` and same goes for the discriminator `user.discriminator`. You can refer to the code below :

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, member : discord.Member, *,reason = None) :
  user = member.discriminator
  await ctx.send(f" User Tag is : {user} ")
```

In the example above, I set a command `test` and user must tag someone after a command like:
`!test @Victor Chung`  and  `!` is a `command_prefix`.
Thank You :)